# Profiling python fabric commands in each task

Tags: python, profiling, fabric

How can I profile python fabric? I need to know which command in a task takes most time.

Say I have a fabfile.py which has 1 task. To perform this it passess 10 commands though ssh. When I run, it should output the time each command took and sort it.

I searched the fabric documentation. Didn't find any way to write plugin/hook etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `time`

for task level duration:

```
$time fab command
```

for command level duration `time` can be injected in task definition:

```
def status():
""" Is our app live? """
sudo("time forever list")
```

Apart from that the trivial time duration can be decorated

```
    from timeit import default_timer as timer

    start = timer()
    # ...run('run a command')
    end = timer()
    print(end - start)
```

Theres hardly any support from fabric wiki and project regarding this, but will be a exciting add-on to develop.

Comment: `time` wont provide what I want. It'll just provide the total duration of a command. But I am looking for a easy profiler. Right now I am doing this using custom decorator. That way I can only time at task level, but I want to do it at command level.

Comment: -1. `time` is way too coarse-grained. A good solution to this should provide a breakdown of time spent on a per-function (or per-task) basis